# Is this code using JupyterDash or plotly dash?

Tags: jupyter, plotly-dash

The following code looks like it's a combination of both plotly dash and Jupyter dash and it was run via jupyter notebook. Can someone explain why both jupyter dash and plotly dash need to be used together?

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, no_update
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Scatter(
        x=df['x_lv'], #x_px and y_px for pixel data
        y=df['y_lv'], 
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(color=df['color']), showlegend=True
    )
])


# turn off native plotly.js hover effects - make sure to use
# hoverinfo="none" rather than "skip" which also halts events.
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo="none", hovertemplate=None)

server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="graph-basic-2", figure=fig, clear_on_unhover=True),
    dcc.Tooltip(id="graph-tooltip"),  html.Div(id="debug"), 
])




@app.callback(
    Output("graph-tooltip", "show"),
    Output("graph-tooltip", "bbox"),
    Output("graph-tooltip", "children"),
    Input("graph-basic-2", "hoverData"),
)
def display_hover(hoverData):
    if hoverData is None:
        return False, no_update, no_update

    # demo only shows the first point, but other points may also be available
    pt = hoverData["points"][0]
    bbox = pt["bbox"]
    num = pt["pointNumber"]

app.run_server(mode="inline", host="localhost",port=8052)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by both Plotly Dash and Jupyter Dash, but in the code you have provided, the server being used is JupyterDash to allow viewing dash applications in a Jupyter notebook. As for Plotly Dash, you can only build components using Plotly Dash, so even though you are running a JupyterDash server, you'll still need to use Plotly Dash to build the components for it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted uses a JupyterDash *app*, identifiable from the line `app = JupyterDash(__name__)`. However, it uses Dash *components* as part of the app, because  JupyterDash (which is by the way developed by plotly, as is the "original" Dash) is basically the same thing as Dash, but tailored to run from within a Jupyter notebook. So a JupyterDash app can be built just like a Dash app, but will provide extra features for a smooth user experience in a Jupyter notebook.

For more details, I suggest reading [the announcement of JupyterDash from plotly](https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-jupyterdash-811f1f57c02e).